# C/C++ difference and

Tags: c++, c, class

I have a vendor specifc code for ADC and other peripherals.
Now using it I am understanding the flow.

the extension of the files are .cpp but the statements there are similar to C rather C++
i.e. printf() is used instead of cout;
no namespace.std defined... also other things which made me sure that it is a c-language code.
(pardon me but whatever I ask the vendors but response is quite late from there)

So it is a complete C- code. But while understangin I came to a point where the class is defined and I am really puzzled now. Since I have not seen or heard any one using class

```
C4DSPBlast cBlast;
cBlast.GetBlastInfo();
```

where  C4DSPBlast cBlast;

and following code shows that C4DSPBlast is a class. Now, while debugging, I found that I am getting error at exactly this statement   cBlast.GetBlastInfo();
but since I don't know the classes in C- I post it here since I am not getting any forward any further in debugging.

```
class C4DSPBlast
{
public:

    //! empty constructor.
    C4DSPBlast(void);
    //! empty destructor.
    ~C4DSPBlast(void);

    //! Get BLAST information from the hardware(firmware). 
    /*!
     * Read the BLAST information from an the PCI memory attached to the hardware device. This function populates internal class members with this information.
     * @return  CBLAST_IO_ERROR_BLAST_INFO_RD, CBLAST_NO_DEV_TYPE or CBLAST_SUCCESS if no errors.
     */
    int GetBlastInfo(void);

    //! m_valBLASTRegister the standard BLAST information register.
    union { BLASTReg m_BLASTRegister; unsigned long m_val0; } m_valBLASTRegister;   

    //! m_valBLASTRegisterExt the extended BLAST information register.
    union { BLASTReg m_BLASTRegisterExt; unsigned long m_val1; } m_valBLASTRegisterExt;

    //! The whole BLAST information populated by GetBlastInfo() as a C data structure.
    struct BOARD m_cBoard;
};
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Comment: Do you have definition of GetBlastInfo()?

Comment: plain C doesn't have classes, however is often use for hw related libraries. therefore I suspect it's old legacy code, so it's not strange not to find namespaces or heavy iostream usage. However what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you please fix the title? Makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: It is quite commong for C programming to program in C but use some C++ keywords (like classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is C++. Compile it as C++ and the errors will disappear.

Comment: yes, the class and public keywords show this is C++ (as well as constructor/destructor pair).  Sometimes, depending on what libraries are available, you will see C style standard IO and no namespace keywords, or virtual functions or templates, or other things that sometimes attributed to "code bloat".  (FWIW, you would have to run some tests with your specific tools to see what contributes to bloat and what is optimized out.)

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are different languages. Current common convention is that if you give file with an extension `.c` to the compiler, it will compile it as C file. If you give it a `.cpp` or `.cxx` (exact list depends on the compiler) it will process it as C++ file. This will work even if you put mixture of C/C++ files on the same command line.

If you pick up arbitrary C file, rename to `.cpp`, and give it to compiler, 99% chance that it will be compiled. C++ standard describes a list of incompatibilities with C, but these are rather rare things.

Most likely that you see a file that was created as C and then started its new life as C++.

Comment: Actually, there are quite a few things that are valid C but invalid C++, but most are related to the relatively relaxed C type system and they should be trivial to fix (add a cast).

Comment: Right, even if some problem will be discovered, most likely it will be  easy (trivial is maybe too much) to fix.